# how to let user choice in alert javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get an answer from users in my website using javascript `alert()`

1. User Clicks button and Alert pops up
2. User Clicks on Yes or No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the JavaScript Alert(), there's a similar one called confirm().

For instance,
`confirm("Pick true or false");`

That "Pick True or False" is the text to be displayed, and then you have to pick between confirm or cancel. Also, you can make some if statements, based on the confirm pick.

Comment: "True" or "False " is not "the text to be displayed" it is the return value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Answer (score 3):

Use [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) to have a yes / no (cancel) option.

```
var txt;
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r === true) {
  txt = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
  txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

[image]

or [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) if you want the user to type something

```
var userInput = prompt("Please enter your name");
```